# Can't update ComboBox linked to another ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

I can't update ComboBox that is linked to another ComboBox. I have one ComboBox that has countries and the other has cities. When I select a country, cityComboBox shows me the cities inside it, but when I change Country it still shows me the same cities. Here is my code

```
//method to get the cities    
public IEnumerable<Ciudad> GetCP(int a) {
    string SelectCP = "SELECT [ciudadID],[nombre] FROM [proyectoZoo].[dbo].[Ciudad] where [paisID]=" + a + "";
    List<Ciudad> Ciudades = new List<Ciudad>();
    foreach (IDataReader reader in this.Execute(SelectCP)) {
        Ciudad ciudad = new Ciudad();
        ciudad.ciudadID = reader.GetInt32(0);
        ciudad.nombre = reader.GetString(1);
        Ciudades.Add(ciudad);
    }
    return Ciudades;
}
```

Windows form:

```
IEnumerable<Country> Countries = server.GetCountries();
cmbPais.DataSource = Countries;

IEnumerable<Ciudad> Ciudades = server.GetCP((int)cmbPais.SelectedValue);
cmbCiudad.DataSource = Ciudades;
```

Comment: What is the initial value of the property SelectedValue here? Try to put a breakpoint on that line and check the value of the property passed to GetCP

Comment: it starts with the id of the first country. its walways sending that id

Comment: Have you tried to use the `SelectedIndex` property of the combobox?

Comment: It is not clear where the second part of your code is executed. Is It part of the SelectedIndexChanged event for the countries combo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this code for the SelectedIndexChanged event handler of cmbPais

```
void cmbPais_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(cmbPais.SelectedValue != null)
    {
       IEnumerable<Ciudad> Ciudades = server.GetCP((int)cmbPais.SelectedValue);
       cmbCiudad.DataSource = Ciudades;
    }
}
```